# Sliding expiration with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-security

I'm using Spring Security and I've noticed that, when a user logs in, the authentication cookie will be valid for about a day. It doesn't seem to 'refresh' this expiration date - the cookie expires after a day, even if 5 minutes before the end of that day I've made a request to the server on a secured URL.

How can I set up sliding expiration for authentication cookies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its quite easy to add custom filter that will inspect the cookie and re-set it to later expiration if needed (to see the proper way of doing those, you can take a look at `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter` and `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.AbstractRememberMeServices#setCookie`), though I'd consider not extending the cookie expiration by the same amount as successful login (but just beyond the session expiration); in addition, I'd guess there is no need to touch cookie on each request, but only if there is a certain minimal amount of time left to the cookie expiration.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will look at the classes you mentioned. I disagree though with the cookie not having to be touched on every request if you want true 'remember me' functionality. You never know what request might be the last one for a long time.