# does it happen when cookie expires but session still active?

Tags: session, cookies

When user login, write a login cookie to browser with max-age 30 minutes, during this time user keeps on operating, after 30 minutes does the login cookie would be expired but session is still active? is there a mechanism to renew cookie expire time or some else?

Comment: Depends. Please tag a language, operating system, or web server so we can provide an accurate answer for the technology you use.

Comment: @JohnWu, Linux, java language, nginx server, chrome.

Comment: @JohnWu, spring + springmvc + mybatis framework.

Comment: is app server smart enough to renew cookie expire time before cookie is going to be expired?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sliding expiration with Spring Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858210/sliding-expiration-with-spring-security)

Comment: @JohnWu， thanks for the URL.